# How to get number of records outputted by Mappers in the Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to know the number of records that Mappers outputted in the Reducer. There is only one Reducer, so I guess that simplifies things.

My first thought was to increment a counter in the mappers and get it in reducer, later I found that such a counter already exists, but it seems like it's "not meant" to be read from reducer, but only from the driver.

Should I use counters and how to do it correctly, or is there any other way?

Comment: Add a manual counter in your mapper code and from mappers cleanup method, emit it as 
<CustomKey, count value>
From the reducer you can aggregate the values for this given key

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to know the number of records while iterating through values in reducer, so this won't be adequate...

Comment: Can you clarify "number of records". Is that not the total number of records processed by a mapper? Well for that you can make your custom key the first one in the sort order so that it comes to the reducer first. There you can store it to a local variable.

Comment: @ArunAK I'm interested in the number of records emitted by mapper. Not all the records that mappers get have to be emitted. Yes, I realize I could make such a workaround, but I was hopping to use counters if possible, since it looks more elegant and understandable. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are inherent counters that you can leverage which even get dumped out at the end of your MR job.  Search for "Map output records" on https://martin.atlassian.net/wiki/x/SYBmAQ to see an example of the total number of records read.

You can also create your own counters as see by the "WordsByLength" one in https://github.com/lestermartin/hadoop-exploration/blob/master/src/main/java/lestermartin/hadoop/exploration/wordcount/WordSizeMapper.java.

Comment: But I don't want to get counters at the end of the job, but in the reducers, as I explained.